# Какой язык выбрать для подсветки?

Tags: bat

На Хабре выкладываю код батника. Предусмотрена ли там подсветка для этого языка? Вообще, как называется язык, на котором пишутся батники? Или это и не язык никакой?

Comment: powershell, dos или (но вряд ли) bash. Но вообще, почему бы не спросить на самом хабре?

Comment: Хм.. Есть такой язык dos? Если есть, то, вероятно, его.

Comment: А вообще батники на чем пишут?

Comment: @Qwertiy на хабре для подсветки есть.

Comment: 1. Выбирай `dos`. 2. Если не понравится, переключай пока не устроит результат. 3. Если совсем не нравится, отключи подсветку. 4. Батники пишут на bat или batch.

Comment: `bash` есть, но, как и `dos`, не выделяет,  к примеру, символ перенаправления, не то. Вообщем, оставлю без выделения.